# Save User Geo Point in Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, geolocation

I am trying to save the user's location as a PFgeopoint to a custom parse class named: User. Nothing is saving and I can't find anything in the parse docs to figure out my error. Please help!

```
  let user = PFObject(className:"User")


        PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground {
            (geoPoint: PFGeoPoint?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                user.setObject(geoPoint!, forKey: "Location")
            } else {
                user.setObject(geoPoint!, forKey: "Location")
            }
        }
```

Comment: is that a class named "User" or is that [a PFUser object](https://parse.com/docs/osx/api/Classes/PFUser.html) or subclass?  also, you should edit your question to show how you are saving your user object.

Comment: It's a custom class named User, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to save the user location to parse, you must get it from the device
using the `CLLocationManager`then save it into a PFGeoPoint

```
var manager = CLLocationManager()
var loc =  manager.location.coordinate
var actualLocation = PFGeoPoint(latitude:loc.latitude,longitude:loc.longitude)
 let object = PFObject(className:"User")
 object["Location"] = actualLocation
object.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (_success:Bool, _error:NSError?) -> Void in
            if _error == nil
            {
              // yay its saved
            }
```

Comment: Glad I was able to help you

Comment: @Lamour when i apply your solution i get thread1: exc_bad_instruction(code=exc_1386_invop, subcode=0x0) when I try to run it. However before i run it i get no errors...any idea what im doing wrong?

Comment: @MatthewSingleton you have to post which line or your code in order for me to tell you what's the problem

Comment: @Lamour For some reason the error is no longer on that line...it jumped down to the next section of code which worked fine before   self.mapView.delegate = self

Comment: @MatthewSingleton what was the problem ?

Comment: well the problem was that i was setting some variables before others were being set and they needed to be afterwards..that got it to work....BUT i only wanted that code to work in an action button so I cut and pasted that code into the action bottom still AFTER and now it only works on my iphone not the simulator....i dont know why

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a query? Ex:

```
    PFQuery query = PFQuery(classname:"User")
    query.whereKey("GUID", equalTo: GUID)
    NSArray users = query.findObjects()

    var user = users.firstObject();

    PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground {
        (geoPoint: PFGeoPoint?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            user.setObject(geoPoint!, forKey: "Location")
        } else {
            user.setObject(geoPoint!, forKey: "Location")
        }
    }
```